# Why is my build taking so long?

Tags: android, build

Yesterday I home worked, and I had the surprise to see that my build time was approximatively 3-4 seconds on my personal laptop whereas it's taking over 5 minutes on my way more powerfull computer at work..

I have the same os on both (ubuntu 14.04 lts), I use the same jdk (open jdk 1.7), the only thing that differs is my IDE, I'm still on Android studio 1.5 at home, and I use 2.0 at work.3-4, I'm currently downloading the old ide but I doubt that it could be the problem here and I wanted to get the stackoverflow community's opinion on this one.

Where should I look at ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have seen this difference as well. I am guessing it has something to do with "Instant Run" feature they've added in 2.0

Comment: By default, gradle uses internet to check if it uses the latest version. Perhaps the internet connection is slower at your work?

Comment: @camelCaseCoder I had the same feedback from a collegue few minuts ago, I really surprises me, I my case even the slightest "hot" swap is taking longer than a full build on my laptop. 0xDEADC0DE the connexion at my work is way better than at my place..

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2.0 has introduced new feature called "Instant run" to minimize the build time between updates to your app. Although your first build may take longer to complete, Instant Run pushes subsequent updates to your app without building a new APK, so changes are visible much more quickly.

You can go through the document provided by Android for more information

[Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run) and [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html)

Comment: Well, I'm well aware of that but It never takes less that than what my 1.5 ide takes for a full build. Even if I only change a white space in a .java

Comment: I feel that's the problem with latest build itself. Please read **'Improve build times by configuring DEX resources'** in the first link which I have given. Hope that helps solving your problem.

Comment: Yep I've done that already, didn't notice any game breaking changes, I've also activated parallel and daemon but again.. no real improvement

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've download the same ide than my laptop's, and it's as long as with 2.0.. So I'm back to square 1 and I don't know where to look for. It cannot be something that's on git, same ide, same os, same jdk..